# log parser doesn't interpret dates correctly

Tags: iis, logging, logparser

When I query our IIS logs, I get a value of '30/12/1899' in the date column.

```
select * from 'C:\IIS 2013 Logs\*.log'
```

However for some rows, it does have a valid date. (Coincidently rows that have a day number less than or equal to 12) So immediately you can tell it's a date formatting issue.

Our IIS is logging in american date format (mm-dd-yyyy) - I cannot change this. Our server however runs on UK date format (dd-mm-yyyy).

Is there an extra argument I can give log parser so that it grabs the dates correctly from our americanized logs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-locale:USA`command-line flag to tell logparser that the dates in the log are in US format.